# How do I confirm login to Rally when using Java and the RallyRestApi object?

Tags: java, rest, rally

I am writing a web service client for accessing Rally using Java and the Rally API, and would like to confirm that a user has entered the correct username/password when logging in (which occurs during the creation of the RallyRestApi object).  The only way I have found so far to show if their credentials worked was to just attempt a query and check for a response.  Does RallyRestApi give any feedback that would indicate a correct login, or can anyone recommend a method that would validate the user/password information?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a test query right now is really the only way to do that.  Specify a page size of 1 to limit your results to the minimum for perf reasons.